# Add PostgreSQL databaseas data source for WinForms DataGridView

Tags: postgresql, winforms, datagridview, datasource, visual-studio-2019

I've successfully connected to a PostgreSQL database by **manually** coding it (create connection string for IP address, port, credentials and database name, create the NpgsqlConnection object, and open the connection).

Now I need to add that database as a Data Source for a DataGridView in a WinForms project. I ran across [Devart's dotConnection for PostgreSQL](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/) and downloaded the Express version. They have a [documentation page](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/DDEX.html), but for the life of me I can't figure out how to add the database as a datasource (I also reached out to their support email three days ago, but they've never responded.)

When I click Add New Data Source in the Data Sources tab and the Data Source Configuration Wizard opens, I'm not sure if I should select Database or Object. In any case, I'm not seeing how to add the PostgreSQL database connection information as a datasource through the wizard.

Comment: Why you want to use the wizards? instead of your manual code?

Comment: Try the wizard with a database first and see if that's works. It doesn't matter what database your connecting to. You end up with datasets made of datatables, (etc.) no matter what the underlying data source is. [Here's the wizard walk through using SQL Server and the database option.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-and-configure-datasets-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to do that is not to use the wizards, they hide code in .Designer.cs and .resx files and make maintenance difficult.

I recommend you do something like this programmatically:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = GetData("Your sql");

public DataTable GetData(string selectSql)
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();             
        string connstring = String.Format("Your conn string");

        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(selectSql, conn);         
        da.Fill(ds);                                                           
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }                                                      
}
```